# Android Shape Rectangle with 2 colors

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to make a custom rectangle that should use hex colors from **#bff54a** up to **#88c010**.

[image: Rectangle two colors]

Actually I have this xml but I can only use one of those colors. How can I make the gradient possible? I already searched and I didn't found anything like this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray_light" />

<solid android:color="#88c010" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gradient as the color of the Drawable :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray_light" />

  <gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="0"
    android:centerY="1"
    android:startColor="#bff54a"
    android:endColor="#88c010" />

  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

See [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: Can you explain the crash woth "radial" ? (stack trace or smthg)

Answer (score 0):

You can create file shape and implement this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangule"> <!-- oval -->
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#388E3C"
                android:endColor="#448AFF"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Result**

[image]